# how to remove small gaps between widgets inside a column

Tags: flutter, dart

there is always a very small **empty gap** between my `widgets` inside my `Column` that is not visible in the flutter inspector. Does anyone know why this happens? and how can I fix it?.

For now **I transform.translate** one of the `widgets` by 1 in the y direction **to hide the gap** but it seems like a very amateur fix. making the border `width` 0 also didn't fix it. I see a few other threads about this but none seems to have a solution. Is it **an internal bug** that needs to be fixed by flutter devs?
thanks everyone in advance for their time

Edit:
The code is kind of long but since you guys asked I will add it here. But its exactly as I said and no use of column properties alignments or other seems to fix it, I checked there are no extra paddings.

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Center(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(...),
                if(blurAnimation.value!=0 && editFocusSubTask) Opacity(...),
                Container(
                  width:100.vw(context),
                  height: 100.vh(context),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.getPadding(context).top,bottom: 1.getPadding(context).bottom),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: double.maxFinite,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assets/sideImage.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                        ),//image(1)
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: double.maxFinite,
                        height: 70,
                        // color:  const Color.fromRGBO(247, 218, 210, 1),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Stack(...),//textField(2)
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 25,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
        )
    );
```

and this is a screenshot of the render.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lGbw.jpg]
near the bottom you can see that there is  a small gap between the image (1) and the text field container (2) through which you can see the background color of the scaffold and in case any of you ask there is no empty space or something in the png I checked that aswell but the issue is with the image.asset(), since when I made a normal container with max width there was no empty space.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of this so we can inspect it?  Include the code by editing this question.

Comment: Could be related to the widget itself. What widgets are inside the Column?

Comment: In your column's children, wrap all the widgets in a `Container` widget with different `color` parameter, that way you can see the actual `padding` of each widget which has nothing to do with the `column` widget itself

Comment: This is indeed an internal bug in flutter framework.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for that.

**1. Padding & margins:**

you need to remove padding and margins. For example if you have container widget.

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```

**2. Use of `MainAxisAlignment` and `CrossAxisAlignment`**

If you are using these properties in `Column`, it will also give space

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
```

or

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
```

you can read more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html).

**3. Container Constraints:**

Check if any of your widgets or containers have specific height constraints that might be causing the gap. You can verify by giving `color`

**4. Use of `Expanded`**

You can use `Expanded` widget to occupy extra space. Read [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)